# Temp procedure messes up collation

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure, collation, tempdb

Issue:
i have a procedure (simplified), created by .NET application:

```
create procedure #SaveData
@InValue varchar(128)
as
begin
    insert into Production.TargetTable (PREFIX_Value) select @InValue
end
```

Problem is, the database uses **SQL_SLOVAK_CP1250_CI_AS** collation.
TempDB uses default **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** collation.

Problem simplified:

```
-- this doesnt work, returns RTC
create procedure #SaveData
@InValue varchar(128)
as
begin
    select @InValue
end

-- this doesnt work, returns RTC
create procedure #SaveData
@InValue varchar(128)
as
begin
    select @InValue collate SQL_SLOVAK_CP1250_CI_AS
end

-- this does work, returns ŘŤČ
create procedure SaveData
@InValue varchar(128)
as
begin
    select @InValue
end
```

Which causes that instead for instead of test string **ŘŤČ**, **RTC** is saved.
When i remove the # from the Procedure name and dont create it as a temp procedure, everything works.

Now, one fix found to work, is to change the param type from varchar to nvarchar. But this would be a lot of work (many different procedures). Is there any global approach that could work?

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Maybe you should change your server's collation to SQL_SLOVAK_CP1250_CI_AS?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin will try, but seems like a nuke option. Could be other databases running on the server at the same time with different collations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in column collation. Any value passed to it will have its collation changed to column collation:

```
declare @table table(txt varchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
insert into @table values ('ŘŤČ' collate SQL_SLOVAK_CP1250_CI_AS)
--result will be changed, even with explicit collation
select * from @table
go

declare @table table(txt varchar(10) collate SQL_SLOVAK_CP1250_CI_AS)
insert into @table values ('ŘŤČ')
--correct output
select * from @table
go
```

So you have to change collation in column:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME alter column TextCol varchar(...) collate SQL_SLOVAK_CP1250_CI_AS
```

Comment: Thx but nope, would say the collate comes too late, after the param gets passed to the procedure, it gets 'truncated' to Latin1 collation

Comment: True, but the temp procedure stores into a normal, non-temp, table and there the collation is ok.

Comment: Temporary objects are held in master db, which has latin collation. Without `#` you create this procedure in one of your databases, which (most likely) has slovak collation. Thus the difference.

Comment: I understand that, the question is, how can i really use tempdb (and mostly temp procedures) with different databases that have differetn collations.

Comment: Then, in procedure, you have to explicitly collate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160791/discussion-between-vladislav-zalesak-and-michal-turczyn).